# where can i find my backup file in pdadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npZuD.png)when using pgadmin4 ,i have download a backup file in storage manager ,but where can i find it in my computer?i want to find it in my computer and then add it to my local postgre database.Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try the DBA stackExchange.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.